# Reading timing diagram correctly?

Tags: spi, timing, diagram

I have the following timing diagram of a SPI communication.

Am I calculating total time T for receiving 24 bits correctly?

Diagram: [image: Timing diagram]

Comment: No, because these timing constraints are extrema (minimum and maximum required/guaranteed intervals). What exactly are you trying to calculate (and why - this sounds like it could be an X-Y problem)?

Comment: Well, I want to know the theoretical minimum time required at max frequency. I don't really know how you should calculate it otherwise than taking the T_min/T_max times (while the IC is communicating at it's max. frequency) of a timing diagram. To me it makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you want the theoretical minimum then you can do it this way. As long as you know it's likely not the exact timing any particular MCU will have (unless you build the driving circuit yourself with unrealistic precision).